# missing entry for search statistics geonetwork 3.10.1 / war file installation

Tags: geonetwork

Installed the geonetwork version 3.10.1 from War File (Tomcat 7). Elasticsearch 7.2, Kibana 7.2 running on seperated servers. What we did:

**Elasticsearch:**

Load the indexes:

```bsh
curl -O https://raw.githubusercontent.com/geonetwork/core-geonetwork/10.0.1/es/config/features.json

curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -X PUT http://host:9200/gn-features -d @features.json

curl -O https://raw.githubusercontent.com/geonetwork/core-geonetwork/10.0.1/es/config/records.json

curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -X PUT http://host:9200/gn-records -d @records.json 

curl -O https://raw.githubusercontent.com/geonetwork/core-geonetwork/10.0.1/es/config/searchlogs.json

curl -X -H 'Content-Type: application/json' PUT http://host:9200/gn-searchlogs -d @searchlogs.json
```

**Kibana:**

- Set `server.basePath`: `"/dashboards"` #war File is deployed as tomcat ROOT.
- Set `kibana.index` `".dashboards"`.
- Import the `export.json` from https://github.com/geonetwork/core-geonetwork/blob/master/es/es-dashboards/data/export.json under saved objects in kibana.

**GeoNetwork:**

- Comment `<!--<filter-mapping> <filter-name>XFrameOptionsFilter</filter-name> <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern> </filter-mapping>-->` in web.xml.
- Set parameters in `config.properties` file for (searchlog,records,features) `index`, `kb.url` and `es.url`.
- Set `spring.profiles.active` value = `"es"` for dashboard in `web.xml`.

**Health check:**

1. CswGetCapabilitiesHealthCheck: OK

   - CswGetRecordsHealthCheck: OK
   - DashboardAppHealthCheck: OK   Dashboard application is running.
   - DatabaseHealthCheck: OK
   - DeadlockedThreadsHealthCheck: OK
   - FieldCacheSanityHealthCheck: OK
   - Free file handles: OK
   - FreeConnectionsHealthCheck: OK
   - HarvestersHealthCheck: OK
   - IndexHealthCheck: OK   0 records indexed in remote index currently.
   - LuceneIndexHealthCheck: OK
   - NoIndexErrorsHealthCheck: OK

but now only content statistics works; the entry for search statistics is missing.
Hope someone here have an idea where my mistake is.

Here the missing search statistics enty:

[image: Admin Console / Status and Statistics]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search statistics are not available in 3.8+ versions

View [Github issue](https://github.com/geonetwork/core-geonetwork/issues/4499):

> Search statistics were disabled in 3.8 version due to the upgrade of ElasticSearch / Kibana. Seem the dashboards require some re-work.
>
> Created this issue to track this. In the meantime, maybe would be good to hide the option to enable search statistics from the Administration settings and update the manual so it's clear.

Comment: Thank you very much !